# In Lightroom, can I make sidebars horizontal (for use on a monitor in portrait orientation)?

Tags: lightroom, software

I am using my monitor and Lightroom in portrait mode, but the sidebars in the develop module (with histogram, loupe and editing options) squeeze pictures to be unnecessarily small. Is it possible to make them horizontal at the top and bottom of the screen instead?

Comment: IIRC, no, but [TAB] toggles them.

Comment: Photoshop gets an [update for custom toolbars](http://www.engadget.com/2015/12/01/adobe-photoshop-custom-toolbars-artboards/), would be interesting to see if that's gonna be ported to Lightroom and could help with your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot move the sidebar (both the left preset and right processing) bars on top of bottom. You can rather adjust their pane length and also show/hide them if necessary. The main reason they could not give this option is, there is already other panels situated at the bottom of the panel - the photo roll panel at the bottom, where you can choose any photo in the selection anytime. And the filter panel at the top - with which you can sort and filter the current selection of photos in the developer mode.